# attach model to link

Tags: gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I've been trying to attach a static model to a link of a mobile robot. Somehow this is completely ignored by gazebo and I don't know why. Please see the code below:

```
        physics::WorldPtr world = physics::get_world();
        physics::ModelPtr test_model = world->GetModel("test_model");

        physics::LinkPtr link = model->GetLink("link3");
        math::Pose pose;
        pose.Set(1,1,1,0,0,0);
        link->AttachStaticModel(test_model,pose);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1462/attach-model-to-link/) by [Max Stähr](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/224/max-st%C3%A4hr/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-02-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ffurrer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28/ffurrer/) on 2013-02-20**:
in what context are you doing this? in a plugin? maybe you could provide us with a file that we could test with.

**Comment by [Max Stähr](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/224/max-st%C3%A4hr/) on 2013-02-21**:
Hi,
I cant upload a file because of my insufficient karma < 10.

**Comment by [Max Stähr](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/224/max-st%C3%A4hr/) on 2013-02-21**:
The code is called within the ConnectWorldUpdateStart callback, so it should been updated in every simulation cycle. Is there another way to provide you the file?

**Comment by [ffurrer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28/ffurrer/) on 2013-02-21**:
yes, pastebin.com should work, in the case you can't put the link in directly just use some spaces in the link :S. Is there a reason why you're not using SDF for that matter? Do you want to change the attachment state during runtime? Otherwise you can use something like in this tutorial: [http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.4/build\_robot/attach\_gripper](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.4/build%5C_robot/attach%5C_gripper)

**Comment by [Max Stähr](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/224/max-st%C3%A4hr/) on 2013-02-27**:
Hi,
I've just added the file. Can you see the problem?

http://pastebin.com/EECvY9Tn

**Comment by [Max Stähr](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/224/max-st%C3%A4hr/) on 2013-02-27**:
Hi,
I've just added the file. Can you see the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

A note about your pasted code: Pausing and unpausing the world within an update call does nothing.

Is `camera_model` a static model?

Make sure to detach a static model before attaching it to a different link.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0